# Hide option in materialize select box

Tags: jquery, materialize

Materialize docs - http://materializecss.com/forms.html

I want to hide Materialize select option by jquery. I added a class to an option and by using this code `$('.break_5').hide();` option is hidden successfully. But it is displayed in Materialize select box.

Comment: Maybe you should remove that `$('.break_5').remove();`

Comment: I want show again that option box in another condition thats why i am using hide(), but it not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, in order to update the items inside the select, you must destroy the material and rerun initialization.

```
$('#mySelectID').material_select('destroy');
```

Then recreate your select with or without certain options and initialize new select.

```
$('#mySelectID option').hasClass('break_5').remove();
$('#mySelectID').material_select();
```

Comment: But i dont want to use remove because if we use remove then not able to show again in other conditions. And hide is not working.

Comment: You may then want to store each possible option in a global javascript variable so you can add them back easier. But this is how the docs for your plugin say to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The framework has changed since this answer, so here we go:

```
let _select: M.FormSelect;
function InitSelect(): void {
  _select = M.FormSelect.init($('#your-select'))[0];
}

function RecreateSelectItems(userIsAdmin: boolean): void {
  _select.destroy();
  if (!userIsAdmin) {
    $('#your-select option.only-admin').remove();
  }

  InitSelect();
}
```

It's typescript, but you get the idea :)
Cheers.

Comment: Off-note: the [`destroy`](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/select.js#L66) method is mostly concerned with removing listeners to prevent leaks, but it is [implicitly called](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/824e78248b3de81e383445e76ffb04cc3264fe7d/js/component.js#L17) in the `init` method of the parent `Component` class, so there is no need to call it separately during reinitializion, only if the teardown in intended to be permanent